# Re-packetize h264 bytestream to Matroska output

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, quicktime, matroska

I have an app that's capturing multiple video streams from users and put them into one mkv output file.

Data are from RTP packets. I use h264.

I'm creating mkv using ffmpeg and `bytedeco/javacpp-presets` bridge for Java.

For some reason my output mkv, after changed container to mp4 (`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy output.mp4`) is not playable by QuickTime Player. It opens the file but shows nothing but black frame for whole duration.

I'm trying to avoid re-coding of the streams.

One of my attempts to fix this was to somehow pack up raw h264 bytestream and use ffmpeg to put it in mkv again:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -f h264 - | ffmpeg -i - -c copy output.mkv`

But because raw h264 bytestream has no timing information (ffmpeg warns about lack of timestamps here) it packs it with some constant frame rate which results in different video duration than original. So i.e. from 27min video i get 30min with constant frame rate.

I'm looking for a way to re-pack my h264 video data into mkv container without re-coding.

I also tried `NUT` container for raw data as it persists some timing informations but result was the same as original mkv - black frame in QuickTime.

Maybe there is some other way to debug why QT shows nothing for my file? Is there any verbosity mode i can enable, some logs to see if it complains for something?

Answer (score 0):

At the datastream level, you need to extract SPS and PPS items from [H.264's `avcC` Coder Configuration Atoms](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH205-SW51) at the beginning of each file and put them into a [Matroska SimpleBlock](https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html#SimpleBlock) chunk before any other H.264 data.

Or, you can put the avcC data buffer verbatim into your .mkv stream in the header at Segment/Tracks/Track/Codec's private data.

SPS and PPS are standalone NALUs, and Matroska stores them concatenated in [byte stream format](https://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/) in the SimpleBlocks.

H.264 video decoders need the data in SPS and PPS to work.